# R - create dataframe by conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have two simple dataframes

```
a <- data.frame(units = 4512)
b <- data.frame(units = 6200)
```

There is another dataframe with simple conditions

```
price <-
  data.frame(
    from = c(1, 3000, 6000, 10001),
    to = c(3001, 6001, 10001, 999999),
    price = c(25, 22, 20, 17)
  )
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this.

```
a_result <-
  data.frame(
    units = c(3000, 1512),
    price = c(25, 22)
  )

b_result <-
  data.frame(
    units = c(3000, 3000, 200),
    price = c(25, 22, 20)
  )
```

There is defined price in price dataframe price. Depending on units value in a, b rows in result dataframes should be "filled" with maximum possible units.

As you can se, units value in a dataframe is 4512, in category 1-3000 we should fill 3000 units, but in category 3000-6000 we can fill only 1512 units (3000 units was already filled to lower category).

But I'm looking for some function or for simple if else statement. I used to solve this manually, but this required lot of repetitive and ugly code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. Of course, you could make this simpler by having your inputs in a different format, but I've assumed you have it like that for good reason :-)

```
library(dplyr)


f <- function(df, price){
  merge(df, price, all=TRUE) %>%  # Join the number of units on to *each* row of the price table
    mutate(
      interval_length = pmax(pmin(units, to) - from, 0), # Calculate the overlap between each interval and your value
    ) %>%
    filter(
      interval_length > 0  # Remove any prices that aren't applicable
    )
}

f(a, price)  # Make the output table for one input

lapply(list(a,b), f, price)  # Make the output table for all inputs
```